# I cannot deploy and run typescript code after installing firebase tools and initializing /configuring the project

Tags: typescript

When i run npm run-script lint, i get this error:

```bash
Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser.
Occurred while linting /home/user/cloudfunctions/src/index.ts
    at getParserServices (/home/user/cloudfunctions/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils/dist/eslint-utils/getParserServices.js:22:15)
    at create (/home/user/cloudfunctions/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/rules/dot-notation.js:85:81)
    at Object.create (/home/user/cloudfunctions/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils/dist/eslint-utils/RuleCreator.js:41:20)
    at createRuleListeners (/home/user/cloudfunctions/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:870:21)
    at /home/user/cloudfunctions/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:1040:110
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at runRules (/home/user/cloudfunctions/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:977:34)
    at Linter._verifyWithoutProcessors (/home/user/cloudfunctions/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:1330:31)
    at Linter._verifyWithConfigArray (/home/user/cloudfunctions/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:1706:21)
    at Linter.verify (/home/user/cloudfunctions/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:1412:65)
```

Any recommendations on how to fix the error?